# Why am I not able to set a variable as none

Tags: python, kivy

Ok so I am trying to set a variable to `None` so that I can clear it, but each time I do it, I get an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'`. Also I am using Kivy in case that makes a difference. Code is below:

```
if self.ids.txt_inpt1.text != '':
    angA = int(self.ids.txt_inpt1.text)
    print angA
else:
    angA = None
```

Any help is appreciated.

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "solve_triangle.py", line 183, in <module>
 mainApp().run()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
 runTouchApp()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
 EventLoop.window.mainloop()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 403, in mainloop
 self._mainloop()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 290, in _mainloop
 EventLoop.idle()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 330, in idle
 self.dispatch_input()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 315, in dispatch_input
 post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 221, in post_dispatch_input
 listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/private/tmp/pip-build-jshW4M/kivy/kivy/_event.c:7699)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1030, in on_motion
 self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/private/tmp/pip-build-jshW4M/kivy/kivy/_event.c:7699)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1046, in on_touch_down
 if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/private/tmp/pip-build-jshW4M/kivy/kivy/_event.c:7699)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 432, in on_touch_down
 if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/private/tmp/pip-build-jshW4M/kivy/kivy/_event.c:7699)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 432, in on_touch_down
 if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/private/tmp/pip-build-jshW4M/kivy/kivy/_event.c:7699)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 110, in on_touch_down
 self.dispatch('on_press')
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/private/tmp/pip-build-jshW4M/kivy/kivy/_event.c:7654)
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1224, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (/private/tmp/pip-build-jshW4M/kivy/kivy/_event.c:13497)
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1108, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (/private/tmp/pip-build-jshW4M/kivy/kivy/_event.c:12329)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1557, in custom_callback
 exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
File "calculator.kv", line 61, in <module>
 on_press: root.solve_triangle()
File "solve_triangle.py", line 169, in solve_triangle
 self.ids.txt_inpt1.text = angA
File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 22, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__ (/private/tmp/pip-build-jshW4M/kivy/kivy/weakproxy.c:1235)
File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 408, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (/private/tmp/pip-build-jshW4M/kivy/kivy/properties.c:5114)
File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1390, in kivy.properties.AliasProperty.set (/private/tmp/pip-build-jshW4M/kivy/kivy/properties.c:23025)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/textinput.py", line 2849, in _set_text
 text = text.replace(u'\r\n', u'\n')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]; the code you've posted never even refers to `.replace`, for goodness' sake.

Comment: Please put the traceback into your question.  That code is not directly causing the problem; we need some more information.

Comment: Probably there is `angA.replace` somewhere in Your code and there is the case when `angA == None`.

Comment: C'mon people, no need to close this question, there is plenty of information in the traceback, now that the OP has added it to the question. There are much worse questions out there, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834085/failed-to-parse-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs here:

```
File "solve_triangle.py", line 169, in solve_triangle
 self.ids.txt_inpt1.text = angA
```

when you set `angA` to `None` and then assigned to `self.ids.txt_inpt1.text`, the kivy code blows up, since it assumes that the `text` attribute will *always* be a string, not `None`.

If you must assign `angA` to `text`, and `angA` can take a None value, try this:

```
self.ids.txt_input1.text = angA if angA is not None else ''
```

Comment: or refactor your code so that can't press the button to "solve root triangles" if not all values are valid.